# Access runtime from results in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

When I run a `unittest` in Python, I would like to access the time the test took (not each individual testcase but the whole test). This is displayed as part of the result. Is there a way to do this other than just parsing the results string?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no, you can't access the test time directly. At least not without modifying some of the `unittest` classes.

That time is calculated in [TextTestRunner.run](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner) and is not saved as a member of a class, but streamed as a print-out:

```
self.stream.writeln("Ran %d test%s in %.3fs" %
                    (run, run != 1 and "s" or "", timeTaken))
```

If you over-write `TextTestRunner.run` and the method that calls it in `unittest.main`, then you could access the `timeTaken` variable.

**It would be easier to just parse the output text.**

Moreover, since you can now see the `timeTaken` formatting statement used to write that line, you can parse it without risk.

Comment: Interestingly, I was just reading the exact same line in TextTestRunner. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @vectro404 I wrote about 200 lines modifying `TextTestRunner` for you. And I had to override `TestRunner` and over-ide `unittest.main` and so on. Then I realized it was only 3 lines to parse the output stream. I was just too far down the rabbit hole to see the truth.

Comment: @vectro404 We might consider putting in a ticket to expose that `timeTaken` parameter in the results object in the next version of `unittest`. It would be a small change that wouldn't have to affect the API.

Comment: When I searched first up, I saw a module with modifications for time taken to be accessed.